# No sound from speakers - Asus Rog String G17 (G712LW)

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, asus, speakers

A few days ago I bought Asus Rog Strix G17 (G712LW).
Currently i have no sound from speakers on my fresh ubuntu 20.04.01 (latest).

I've tried different advises from google, add some some lines into alsa-base.conf, pulseaudio configs, alsamixer, dual boot from windows (yes, I have dual boot with Win X) with total shut down and so on, but nothing works unfortunately.

I also tried to contact ubuntu. Their support really sucks. I've paid 25 bucks just for nothing and I still wasn't able to contact their tech support.

What is weird for me - its when I start "Try ubuntu" from installation stick - sound is present from speakers. When I install Ubuntu OS - no any sound from speakers anymore. Only headphones are working.

This makes me very sad - 2000$ laptop and no sound at all...
I appreciate any fresh ideas and any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Yes, i checked ... and no any drivers are needed. All drivers installed correctly.

Comment: Same problem here with the G732LWS but I just tried the accepted answer from this thread and it has worked!
https://askubuntu.com/a/1277167/335986 Also,
There's an awesome repo which gives you some keyboard RGB control
https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore Most of the asus function keys don't work, I've tried changing boot flags and a couple other options as well, all to no avail. I've swapped to the latest kernel in the hopes that it was fixed there, but alas no success either Most annoying is the trackpad on/off, but it is picked up by `xinput` so that's not too much of a problem