# No sound ALC294 Asus ROG Strix 512 Ubuntu 20.04.01

Tags: nvidia, sound, alsa, asus, realtek

I just bought a new laptop called Asus ROG Strix G15 G512LW with i7 and Nvidia RTX, but there is no sound at all. Here are some of my device information:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xc5418000 irq 155
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xc5080000 irq 17

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have tried to select HDA Intel PCH from alsamixer and check if there are any muted selection.

Moreover, thanks to [this thread on `snd_hda_intel` options](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568) I tried by adding the ones that listed below to the the alsa base:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

options snd-hda-intel model=g50v
options snd-hda-intel model=g71v
options snd-hda-intel model=dell
options snd-hda-intel model= asus-a7j
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-a7m
options snd-hda-intel model= asus-laptop
options snd-hda-intel  model=lenovo
```

But whatever I tried I cannot made it to hear anything.

BTW when I wrote `alsamixer` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> I got this message:

```
$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such device
So I reached it by writing `alsamixer -c 0` and its version is AlsaMixer v1.2.2
```

It's been a week that I have tried to solve it as a newbie in Ubuntu, so I thought it would be a wise decision to ask your help.

Comment: Do your built in speakers show up in System settings>>>Sound>>>Output?

Comment: It is written as "Speakers - Built-in Audio" corresponds to Output device

Comment: There are some more suggestions [at this link](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

Comment: I tried them all,  but still it does not fixed..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a Asus ROG Strix G17 G712LU-H7009T / Linux Mint 20 (Cinnamon), I faced the same problem (as many Linux users with ALC294 sound chipset). By setting :

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook
```

...in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, I was able to have sound on headphones and internal speakers, but the sound volume does not work properly with this modification (100% or 0% only using the OS sound volume control).

So this is a partial solution but this is better than nothing. I tried many solutions involving hdajackretask or alsa-base.conf, or what's described [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206589#c2) with no luck. ALC294 seems to be a tough one for Linux :).

I added this configuration on https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/audio_intel_hda.

*EDIT*

If like me you experience sound volume troubles (all or nothing) --> https://askubuntu.com/a/1091197/360145

Comment: Thanks for your help, model=asus-zenbook also worked for me, btw it allows me to determine sound level at any stage as well. Thank you again!

Comment: Great :). Good for you if the sound volume control works fine, the all-or-nothing bug is quite annoying !

Comment: My sound volume started to work today after an OS update :)

Comment: Nice :) happy to hear that, at last it will work as expected :)

Comment: Can confirm, the accepted answer works on my G732LWS as well. On the volume control, system volume doesn't affect it at all for me either (0% or 100%). BUT you can control it via pavucontrol.

Comment: This man, yeah this @FlorianMotteau, is a life saver.

Comment: I have spent countless hours trying to get this to work. This is a life saver. Thank you so much.

Comment: This worked wonders for me as well. Just restart after the settings and ENJOY

Answer (score 2):

For volume control after editing "options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook"

try: [My volume is either max volume or muted, no middle ground](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973690/my-volume-is-either-max-volume-or-muted-no-middle-ground)

Comment: You save my day

Comment: Thanks , It worked

Answer (score 0):

Please try these commands in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and then

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Restart and check if sound is back or not.

Comment: i just tried but unfortunately it does not worked, thank you anyway

Comment: It isn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, after I saw the answer under this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234958/no-sound-ubuntu-20-for-dell-i-have-in-settinghdmi-only?rq=1) I tried to use hdajackretask with this commands,

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
Run hdajackretask
```

I saw that default codec was NVIDIA GPU 93, so I tried to change it by following this path;

> select a codec > Realtek ALC294 >apply now

error:

> tee : /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig : Device or resource is busy

I would like to share if it leads any idea..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Asus Rog Strix G712LV. When I installed Ubuntu Studio 20.4, the sound worked flawlessly. After a kernel upgrade, it stopped working.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook
```

worked for me but I could not control the volume any more. The only solution I found was to stick to kernel 5.4.0-42. No more sound with recent kernels (5.4.0-59 and 5.4.0-60).

I know this is not a long term solution as it can lead to security issues.