# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Asus Rog Srix G15 | Win key doesn't work | No sound | Troubles on install

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, sound, 20.04

Clean Asus Rog Srix G15 with:

- i7 10k
- GeForce 2070 Super
- NVme 1 TB

1) I try install clean Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS with options:

- Downloads updates in process
- Install third party drivers

And I got crash. **Solved by** install without this options after install just updated & upgraded.

2) After update & upgrade my Nvidia application just show me blank window. **Solved by** remove nvidia* packages, reboot, install nvidia drivers again from "Drivers"

3) After update something (just by "apt update & apt upgrade") no sound on my PC.
**Solved by** [No sound ALC294 Asus ROG Strix 512 Ubuntu 20.04.01](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276428/no-sound-alc294-asus-rog-strix-512-ubuntu-20-04-01) and works like sucks.

4) After all this troubles on install, after all other small bugs what I report, I got new today: Win (Super)/Fn (Fn+F* hotkeys) doesn't work. Any hotkey don't work, no Win+* actions. After update:

- libinput-bin
- libinput10
- libelput1

UPD. And I don't have: "Software & Updates", no application after this update

UPD 2. Fixed issue with Win just by remove all other languages, but Fn doesn't work

UPD 3. Fixed "Software & Updates" by [Ubuntu Software doesn't open in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04)

And kernel upgrade from 5.4.0-48-generic to 5.4.0-51-generic
I tried all variants with Gnome Tweak Tool but no luck. Please help me because my nervers going out.

Comment: Still no luck with this one? Have you ever tried alter the Settings -> Region&Language -> Input? What about an external usb keyboard? `xev -event keyboard` can be useful. With this i found out, that on my machine (NOT an asus rog) the FN+1 and FN+3 does the same as FN+F10 and FN+F11 on a „normal” keyboard.

Comment: There is also a blog, the last item on some keyboard issues: https://asus-linux.org/blog/updates-2021-05-06/ (i dont say i understand any of this)

Answer (score 0):

I have the ROG G712LWS, and I had the same issue with sound. I tried the temporary solution you mentioned in the question, but I found the working solution for me by this command:

`sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-realtek.conf <<< 'blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek'`