# X/Ubuntu 20.10 on Asus ROG Strix G17 has no sound

Tags: sound, laptop, asus

Just tried Ubuntu and Xubuntu 20.10 on the laptop Asus ROG Strix G17 and it has no sound. Sound worked on a clean install of X/Ubuntu 20.04
Any suggestions?

Comment: Was it installed?  Were you using a RC/beta or the final image?  (a sound issue was fixed only hours before release time so many who downloaded it early or from sites that sync'd early got a *live* that had sound muted  .. it can be fixed in `pavu-control` if this is the issue)

Comment: I just found out the solution described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276428/no-sound-alc294-asus-rog-strix-512-ubuntu-20-04-01 solves my problem.

Comment: Hey @guiverc final version; Just found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276428/no-sound-alc294-asus-rog-strix-512-ubuntu-20-04-01
To find the solution I used alsamixer then looked up for my chip Realtek ALC294

Comment: Thanks for the update @Italo Maia