Speaker audio not working at all on Ubuntu 23.10
Installed Ubuntu 23.10 on my Windows laptop (erased everything, natively running Ubuntu 23.10). My speakers only output audio at the boot chime for my laptop (so I know they work), lspci -vv displays the right sound cards, and settings detects my sound card. Clicking "Test Speaker" shows a volume bar going up then back down, but I don't hear anything. Wired USB headphones work, but the speakers don't work at all after booting. Reinstalled pipewire and pulseaudio many times, checked that everything relevant was unmuted in amixer. I restarted pipewire and wireplumber too.
$ sudo inxi -SMA shows:
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.7-060807-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active (root, process)

I've been troubleshooting for hours and found absolutely nothing that helped. I've even updated the firmware and everything and nothing is working.
$ sudo lspci -vv | grep -A7 -i "audio" shows:
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 165
    IOMMU group: 12
    Region 0: Memory at c5418000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    IOMMU group: 2
    Region 0: Memory at c5080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3

Kernel version from $ uname -a:
Linux ara-1-0 6.8.7-060807-generic #202404170934 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Apr 17 09:46:48 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Laptop model: ROG Strix G532LW_G532LW

What is the model of your laptop? In 23.10, I think you're likely to be running kernel 6.5.0 but it would be useful if you added the output of uname -a to your question. It looks like it might have been fixed in a later kernel (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479661/new-22-04-install-cannot-play-sound-on-speakers)

I've updated my post to include the kernel version. I just updated the kernel like 30 minutes ago so I believe this is the latest one that my laptop supports (6.8.7).

What model is your laptop?

ROG Strix G532LW_G532LW

Have you tried this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276428/no-sound-alc294-asus-rog-strix-512-ubuntu-20-04-01

I get the error "options: command not found" when I tried running options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook

That's not a command, that's a line of text you need to insert into /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf either use a text editor or the command: echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook' >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf then reboot

I tried that and got bash: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf: Permission denied even after adding in sudo at the start and another time with a second sudo in between ' and options.

You can either become root using sudo -s, edit the file manually with sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf or try echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf > /dev/null (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work)

best not to simply copy and paste commands from a random stranger on the internet without having some understanding of what they do :)

You're right about copy pasting from strangers, I edited the file manually and rebooted and now my computer will only boot in CLI mode  still have all my files though

Edit the file again and remove the line that you added (may have been mistyped). Then reboot. You can use nano or pico commands as editors

I removed it, saved it, exited and rebooted and im still stuck in CLI mode. I think this happened because i rebooted as root after doing sudo -s

I doubt that would cause the problem. I suspect there is still an erroneous line in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf or it's been deleted or otherwise modified (empty perhaps)

Apparently something happened and my ubuntu-desktop package got deleted, somehow I was still connected to the internet with my CLI (miracle since it uses PEAP authentication), so I redownloaded it and it fixed that. Audio's still being an issue. Typing the last command you wrote verbatim (the echo one) just gives me a >

Edit: Did it again and it worked but my audio still doesn't work after rebooting.
